# What is the format of HTTP POST data used in Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, api, post, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing with PHP SDK and I would like to send some data via HTTP POST method, as it's mentioned in documentation (e.g. add comment).

At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ they say I should encode the body of HTTP POST request as *...should be formatted as a raw HTTP POST body string, similar to a URL query string*. I can't get the combination of PHP functions to get this to work. In the example they claim following should work:

```
"body": "message=Test status update"
```

Well, that works. But what if I need to add other params? And how should be this string encoded? E.g. I have this:

```
$data = array('name' => 'Gargamel', 'occupation' => 'Freelancing Smurf Hunter');
```

How should I process it to get required format? Following does NOT work:

```
$batch = array();
$query = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'relative_url' => '/forrest/full/of/smurfs',
    'body' => urldecode(http_build_query($data)),
);
$batch[] = $query;
$responses = $this->api('/?batch=' . json_encode($batch, JSON_HEX_AMP), 'POST');
```

I explored half of the Internet, but I can't find any more specific information about the format than the one mentioned above (raw HTTP POST similar to a URL query string).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=331343#p331343

```
    $batch_array[] = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'relative_url' => 'Relative url',
        'body' => 'message=' . 'Your message' . '%26data=' . 'Your data' ,

    );
```

Comment: After some time, I'd say best would be something like this: `str_replace('?', '\u003F', str_replace('&', '\u0026', json_encode($batch_array)));`. Assuming bodies in $batch_array are composed by plain `&` characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is my batch example code:

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];
$friends = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

$batched_request = '[{"method":"GET","relative_url":"'.$friends->data[0]->id.'/likes"}';
for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $batched_request .= ',{"method":"GET","relative_url":"'.$friends->data[$i]->id.'/likes"}';
}
$batched_request .= ']';

$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?batch=' 
    . $batched_request . '&access_token=' . $params['access_token'] . '&method=post';
$posts = file_get_contents($post_url);

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $post = json_decode($posts[$i]->body);
    echo($friends->data[$i]->id.' '.$friends->data[$i]->name);
    //print_r($post);
}
```

Batch query limit 20 requests. You need to decode each part of batch query, see code above.

Comment: Basically, all you wrote I already know. You use GET requests in your batch, that's easy. I am having troubles with sending some data via POST requests (moreover, packed into batch).

Comment: By the way, you should really ease your life by using this https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.

Comment: I wrote code optimization with async sokets. Facebook SDK do not help me this way :) I wrote simple, with file_get_contents for this example.